# Else condition not executed due to try catch

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a scenario in which, when we click on save two process can occur. It can show some messages or else the page can crash. I have added an if condition for the crash and mentioned the other process if the application does not crash as else condition. I have written a code like this to handle the crash.

```
try {
    if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]")).isDisplayed()){
        System.out.println("Critical Error Occured.");
        driver.close();
    } else{
    String msg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/span")).getText();
    if (msg.equals("User already registered")){
        driver.findElement(By.name("dnn$ctr5995$View$btnOk")).click();
        System.out.println(msg);
        driver.close();
    } else if (msg.equals("Admission number already exist.")) {
        driver.findElement(By.name("dnn$ctr5995$View$btnOk")).click();
        System.out.println(msg);
        System.out.println("Please change the admission number.");
        driver.quit();          
    } else if (msg.equals("Saved Successfully.")){
        driver.findElement(By.name("dnn$ctr5995$View$btnOk")).click();
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
    }
}catch ( org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e){
    System.out.println("No Such Element Exception.");
}
```

Since the page crashes rarely, while executing the control goes to catch and so the else conditions for the first if condition is not executed. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Use `finally` clause.

Comment: You are missing a `}` somewhere

Comment: do you have a stack trace? where is the exception thrown?

Comment: There's a flaw here. If the first `findElement` call doesn't find the element (which it might not do, the element could be there, and then a split second might be there but not displayed) it's going to hit the `catch` and not run anything at all. To me, you need that `catch` within the first `findElement`.

Comment: added the missing '}'

Comment: @Arran I dint understand. Can u please explain?

Comment: @Arran I have not pasted the entire code here, in the previous step i had added a wait time so these steps are executed after the page completely loads. I dont knw whether you meant this.

Comment: `findElement` can do two things, throw an exception if it's not there at all and true/false if it's there but not displayed/is displayed. Your logic flow is "if I can find this element, then print 'Critical error occurred' else go on with the next step". Your problem is that if in the "if I find this element", this can, sometimes, throw an exception, which is caught in your *outer* catch. This means that if you are unlucky enough to get caught by that exception, your code will fail and not hit *any* of the further `if`/`else` clauses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do separate `try-catch` blocks inside the sections of the `if` or use a `finally` block for code you always want to execute.

You have two separate issues, the first is the findElement within the conditional. To handle that you need to do the find separately then do the if.

```
Element elem = null
try {
    elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]"));
} catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("No Such Element Exception.");
}
```

Then after that you need to handle it within the else

```
if (elem != null && elem.isDisplayed()){
    System.out.println("Critical Error Occured.");
    driver.close();
} else{
  try {
    String msg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/span")).getText();
    if (msg.equals("User already registered")){
        driver.findElement(By.name("dnn$ctr5995$View$btnOk")).click();
        System.out.println(msg);
        driver.close();
    } else if (msg.equals("Admission number already exist.")) {
        driver.findElement(By.name("dnn$ctr5995$View$btnOk")).click();
        System.out.println(msg);
        System.out.println("Please change the admission number.");
        driver.quit();          
    } else if (msg.equals("Saved Successfully.")){
        driver.findElement(By.name("dnn$ctr5995$View$btnOk")).click();
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
  } catch ( org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e){

  }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to give a try catch block inside the if condition alone as it has shown error for me when i tried it.

Comment: @vignesh inside the conditional you can't, inside the block you can.

Comment: @TimB Sorry i was meaning the block actually

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

May-be you're looking for the  finally clause, aren't you ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally clause can solve your problem. Its best practice to include must  execute code in Finally clause